# run python in classic asp page

Tags: python, python-3.x, asp-classic, iis-10

I have setup python from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and set mapping in IIS to execute *.py scripts by python.exe %s %s. Test.py file works fine.

However when I try to run classic asp file as

```
<script language="Python" runat="server">
def PrintPython():
   print "Hi"
</script>
<%
Call PrintPython()
%>
```

I get "The scripting language 'Python' is not found on the server"

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Please forget about Python in classic ASP, as relevant materials are pretty old, like [2001](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/082201-1.shtml). Classic ASP is long dead. If possible, only use modern Python and run via FastCGI, or reverse proxy.

Answer (score 2):

There's a file called pyscript.py which you need to run to register Python as an ASP scripting language and give it access to COM objects.  If you can't find it in your distribution there's a copy here:

https://github.com/SublimeText/Pywin32/blob/master/lib/x64/win32comext/axscript/client/pyscript.py

It also appears that you need to give the relevant permissions on python.exe to your IUSR account - see this article.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/276494/using-python-scripts-with-iis

I once got python to work in Classic ASP, but it was more than ten years ago, and it could well be that the current version doesn't work, whatever you do.

Comment: Thank you John! I'm here in late 2018 and I do not believe I would have been able to find these resources on my own!